# Multiple exception map

Tags: exception

I have to create a a new exception (MultipleErrorException) which extends MySuperException class. I have another exception (SingleErrorException) which also extends MySuperException.

Looking at the pseudo code below:

```
for (a number of times)
    try
        call myMethod(myObject) that throws SingleErrorException    

    catch(SingleErrorException e)
        add the caught SingleErrorException object to a
        MultipleErrorException object where a mapping should
        be created mapping myObject to SingleErrorException
```

I need to throw a single "MultipleErrorException" which holds a map (myObject-->SingleErrorExceptions).

Is there any other way to this rather than creating an initial MultipleErrorException object before the for loop, an then adding the mappings as the exceptions are caught?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.Exception as such does not have any method to support your requirement.

If you need it, then one way is to add the Map variable in MultipleErrorException and setting the value of it, but again, editing the exception object is not good.

Instead, you can add the error messages to Map and return the map instead of throwing the exception from the method.